# Visualizing empirical PDF from monotonically decreasing density

Tags: probability-or-statistics, visualization

I have a sample from distribution whose density is known to be monotonically decreasing. What's the easiest way to incorporate this information into Mathematica for an empirical density plot?

Looking for something like the estimator [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414916300345) which enforces monotonicity by getting density from slopes of the envelope of the CDF.

[image]

Example data

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
spectralNormalize[vals_] := vals/Max[vals];
empiricalCDF[
   coefs_] := {Most@Sort@coefs, 
    Range[Length@coefs - 1]/Length[coefs]}\[Transpose];
empiricalPDF[
   coefs_] := {Most@Sort@coefs, 
    Most[coefs]*(-1/Differences[coefs])}\[Transpose];

n = 400;
sample := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}]/Sqrt[n];
vals = SingularValueList[sample];

empiricalCDF = 
 ListPlot[empiricalCDF@vals, PlotLabel -> "empirical CDF"]
empiricalPDF = 
 ListPlot[empiricalPDF@vals, PlotLabel -> "empirical PDF"]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is an excellent (and interesting) question about how to incorporate such "additional information".  However, I don't see it as a *Mathematica* question in that if you knew of an appropriate procedure you wouldn't have any trouble implementing it in *Mathematica*.  I think an answer about a method at either CrossValidated or the Math StackExchange would be where you need to go first.  Hence, I'm voting to close the question at this site.

Comment: Also, I suspect (but could certainly be wrong) that there is little information added with the somewhat more vague knowledge that the PDF is monotonically decreasing.  Your other question about adding knowledge of "radial symmetry" is different because that can be explicitly added to kernel density estimators.  With a large sample size the estimated density will be close to being monotonically decreasing.

Comment: You can do this in R with the Grenander Estimator:  https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/fdrtool/html/grenander.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Grenander Estimator is what you're looking for, then here is an implementation using *Mathematica*.

```
n = 100;  (* Sample size *)
SeedRandom[12345];
vals = RandomVariate[#, n] &@MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1];

(* Construct an empircal cdf *)
data = Transpose[{Sort[vals], ConstantArray[1, n]}];
data[[All, 2]] = Accumulate[data[[All, 2]]]/n;

(* Find the smallest concave majorant of the empirical cdf *)
(* This algorithm is probably fragile in that I'm assuming
a particular structure for the result of the ConvexHullRegion function.
Essentially I'm getting rid of the convex hull line segments "underneath"
the smallest concave majorant and including the point {0,0}. *)
ch = ConvexHullRegion[data];
max = Position[ch[[1, All, 2]], Max[ch[[1, All, 2]]]][[1, 1]];
min = Position[ch[[1, All, 2]], Min[ch[[1, All, 2]]]][[1, 1]];
ch = Join[ch[[1, max ;;]], {ch[[1, min]]}, {{0, 0}}];

(* Grenander CDF estimate *)
gCDF[x_] := Piecewise[Join[{{1, x >= Max[vals]}}, 
  Table[{ch[[i, 2]] + (ch[[i - 1, 2]] - ch[[i, 2]]) (x - ch[[i, 1]])/(ch[[i - 1, 1]] - ch[[i, 1]]), 
  ch[[i, 1]] <= x < ch[[i - 1, 1]]}, {i, 2, Length[ch]}]], 0]

(* Grenander PDF estimate *)
gPDF[x_] := Piecewise[Table[{(ch[[i, 2]] - ch[[i - 1, 2]])/(ch[[i, 1]] - ch[[i - 1, 1]]), 
  ch[[i, 1]] <= x <= ch[[i - 1, 1]]}, {i, 2, Length[ch]}], 0]

(* Plot pdfs *)
Plot[{gPDF[x], PDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], x],
  PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[vals, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, ∞}, "Gaussian"}], x]},
  {x, 0, 1.1 Max[vals]}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 2}},
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Red, Black}, Frame -> True,
  PlotLegends -> {"Grenander Estimate", "True density", "Smooth kernel density"},
  PlotLabel -> Style["PDF", 18, Bold, Black]]
```

[image: PDF's]

```
(* Plot cdfs *)
Plot[{gCDF[x], CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[vals], x], CDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], x]},
 {x, 0, 1.1 Max[vals]}, PlotLabel -> Style["CDF", 18, Bold, Black],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1 Max[vals]}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, Exclusions -> None,
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Purple, Red}, PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotLegends -> {"Grenander Estimate", "Empirical CDF", "True CDF"}]
```

[image: CDF's]

Comment: This is great! This was new to me so I did quite a bit of background study first;  I found a lot of mentions of the Grenander Estimator in relevant publications and presentations, but could not find an implementation in mma. If you can work out the fragility kinks, then maybe this might be something worth putting on the wolfram function repository (it also seems this may be widely applicable to more problems)?

Comment: @ydd  Thanks.  I'll have to think more about making the algorithm more stable.  The aspects that do appear stable are (1) the convex hull is correct (not surprised at that) and (2) the points are in counter-clockwise order.

Comment: @tdd Note:  I now don't think my addition of the (0,0) point is appropriate.  While that doesn't appear to matter too much, I'll check on the appropriateness of that shortly.  I have figured out how to get the right "concave majorant of the empirical cdf" from *Mathematica*'s `ConvexHullRegion` function while only relying on the assumption that the points are ordered in counter-clockwise order.  I'll add that in the next few days.

Answer (score 4):

So I think I may be completely missing the mark here (if I am then I can delete this answer in a little bit) and this could be a much more complicated question than I'm qualified to answer, but you could start with the PDF of the `HistogramDistribution`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
vals = RandomVariate[#, 100] &@MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1];

hist = HistogramDistribution[vals, "Scott"]
DiscretePlot[PDF[hist, x], {x, 0, 4, 0.01}]
```

[image]

You can see the PDF is still not monotonically decreasing, but we can extract the PDF values at each bin, and the find the least squares solution that is monotonically decreasing:

```
pdfVals = hist["PDFValues"];
coefs = Array[c, Length@pdfVals];
constraints = Table[c[i + 1] <= c[i], {i, Length@coefs - 1}];
objectiveFunction = Norm[ pdfVals - coefs]^2;
forFit = Join[{objectiveFunction}, constraints];
fittedDecreasing = ArgMin[forFit, coefs];

delims = hist["BinDelimiters"];
booles = 
  Table[Boole[delims[[i]] <= x < delims[[i + 1]]], {i, 
    Length@delims - 1}];
fittedPDF = fittedDecreasing . booles;
DiscretePlot[{PDF[hist, x], fittedPDF}, {x, 0, 4, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thats a neat trick, this might work with manual density estimation too (without binning, density is just the slope between successive points)

Comment: Ah so the CDF of the `EmpiricalDistribution` is just a piecewise function that increases by 1/100 at each value of `vals` right? So the slope at each point of the CDF is something like `0.01/Differences[Sort@vals]` right? And you want the differences of the density to all be less than or equal to zero (monotonically decreasing), so I think this is the same as finding the best fit for `0.01/Differences[Sort@vals,2]` (`where Differences[_,2]` is the second order difference) where everything is <= 0 right? Does that make sense?

Comment: I modified the question to contain an example of computing empirical PDF without binning. I'm hoping monotonicity constraint can make the plot much better without introducing edge artifacts (like `SmoothHistogram[vals]`)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You can get rid of the edge artifacts with `SmoothKernelDistribution[vals, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, \[Infinity]}, "Gaussian"}]` if what you mean by artifacts is the positive density to the left of zero.  Until there is a large sample size, you won't have a monotone decreasing pdf.

Comment: @JimB thanks for the pointer to the Grenander Estimator, this visualization seems to be what I need here

Comment: There is also the use of a bootstrapped Grenander Estimator to obtain pdf confidence intervals:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.2470.pdf.  And that paper also suggests that one can construct kernel estimators which result in monotonic decreasing pdf's that are more efficient than the Grenander Estimator.  I haven't yet digested the whole paper.  This is again about my non-stop sermons about going to CrossValidated first then back here for implementation.  Those folks have far more knowledge about statistics than I have.  (Not all but many or most.)

Comment: @JimB the simplest estimator is just computing the green segments in the plot (in edited question) and then plotting their slopes as a function of x

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

vals = RandomVariate[#, 100] &@MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1];

findDist = (# /. FindDistributionParameters[vals, #] &);
```

Pick several distributions that are monotonic for at least some values of their parameters.

```
distrSym = {
   MarchenkoPasturDistribution[λ, σ],
   MarchenkoPasturDistribution[λ],
   ChiSquareDistribution[ν],
   GammaDistribution[α, β],
   ExponentialDistribution[λ]};
```

Fit distributions to data

```
distr = findDist /@ distrSym

(* {MarchenkoPasturDistribution[0.980962, 1.01724], 
 MarchenkoPasturDistribution[0.986602, 1], ChiSquareDistribution[1.17914], 
 GammaDistribution[0.63868, 1.68378], ExponentialDistribution[0.929888]} *)

labels = StringReplace[ToString /@ distr, "Distribution" -> ""];

fit = NumberForm[#, {5, 3}] & /@ (DistributionFitTest[vals, #] & /@ distr)
```

[image]

```
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"];

Manipulate[
 d = Sort[d];
 Show[
  Histogram[vals, Automatic, "PDF"],
  Plot[
   Evaluate[Tooltip[PDF[#[[1]], x],
       StringForm["``, fit = ``", #[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@
     Transpose[{distr, fit}][[d]]], {x, 0, 4},
   PlotStyle -> colors[[d]],
   PlotLegends -> Placed[
     LineLegend[
      StringForm["``, fit = ``", #[[1]], NumberForm[#[[2]], {5, 3}]] & /@ 
       Transpose[{labels, fit}][[d]]],
     {.6, .7}]],
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ImageSize -> Large],
 {{d, Range[5], "distributions"},
  Thread[Range[Length[distr]] -> labels],
  ControlType -> TogglerBar,
  Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 3}}]
```

[image]

Select the distribution with the best fit.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose a radically simple (to the point of being  stupid) sort of answer.

Why not use the uniform distribution as your kernel? Sounds crazy, but the UniformDistribution[{0, 2 v}] is monotonically decreasing and has a mean value of "v". When you sum them together you get a monotonically decreasing function. Trying it out:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
vals = RandomVariate[#, 100] &@MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1];

myEmpiricalPDF[x_] = 
 (vals /. v_Real -> PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, 2 v}], x] // Mean)
```

Okay, so yes that is an absurd definition and I wouldn't use it in this form in practice. We could write something much better, but if we just look at the result:

```
Plot[{myEmpiricalPDF[x], PDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], x]}, {x, 
  0, 5}]
```

[image]

Doesn't seem bad for the simplest possible kernel (although it wouldn't actually converge to the correct distribution in this case)

I had tons of fun thinking about this, so thanks for posting it. I  considered using  several other kernels that would give smooth results with the same conceptual plan, but this seems to work okay.

Comment: Wow, that plot looks pretty nice. My original motivation was that empirical CDF looks nice, but empirical PDF does not. I have to think some more why this trick works....

Comment: Interesting.  This spreads out the influence of larger observations proportionally more than smaller observations somewhat analogous to an adaptive kernel estimator.  But there doesn't appear to be any control for how much spread is allowed.  I've tried your procedure with larger sample sizes but the fit appears worse as the sample size increases.  But no matter how "crazy" (your words not mine) it appears, the long-term characteristics are what matter.  Have you looked into long-term characteristics of this estimator?

Comment: @jimb I had the same thought, but after sleeping on it, I've decided the bug is actually a feature. We lose resolution on larger values proportional to their value and it's sorta appropriate to lose resolution in the tail of the distribution.