# Bandwidth selection for histograms in bounded domain?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Does anyone have tips how to do proper bandwidth selection to visualize density which is known to be strictly positive?

Example below uses `SmoothHistogram` and `Epanechikov` which have (different problems)

```
(* Generate bounded data *)
genBoundedDatasets[numSteps_] := Module[{},
   d0 = 100;
   numSamples = 100; 
   normalizeFrob2[mat_] := 
    mat/Norm[mat, "Frobenius"] Sqrt[Last@Dimensions[mat]]; 
   randGaussian[m_, n_] := 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {m, n}]/Sqrt[m]; 
   sampler = randGaussian; 
   genMat[{m_, n_}] := normalizeFrob2@sampler[m, n]; 
   mats = genMat /@ Partition[ConstantArray[d0, numSteps], 2, 1]; 
   center[mat_] := (# - Mean[#]) & /@ mat; 
   relu[mat_] := Clip[mat, {0, \[Infinity]}];
   
   xs0 = 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {numSamples, d0}]/Sqrt[d0]; 
   xs = FoldList[center@relu[#1 . #2] &, xs0, mats]; 
   SingularValueList /@ xs
   ];

(* Custom visualization method *)
customHistogram[svals_] := 
 Module[{x}, 
  func = PDF[#, x] &@
    SmoothKernelDistribution[svals, 
     Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 2}, "Epanechnikov"}];
  Show[Plot @@ {func, {x, Min[svals], Max[svals]}}, 
   NumberLinePlot[svals, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3]], PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]


(* Visualize data *)
svals = genBoundedDatasets[10];

Show[SmoothHistogram[#], NumberLinePlot[#]] & /@ svals

customHistogram /@ svals
```

First image shows `SmoothHistogram` where the density crosses over to 0, which I is undesirable as the random variable is known to be positive valued.

[image]

The second image uses `Epanechikov` kernel and has artifacts where density drops to zero unexpectedly, I suspect I'm not selecting the bandwidth properly.

[image]

Comment: It is not a good practice to edit a code, not indicating the changes. In particular, you changed from `SmoothKernelDistribution[svals,  Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Epanechnikov"}]` to `SmoothKernelDistribution[svals,  Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 2}, "Epanechnikov"}]` up to my answer.

Comment: Also your changed code produces plots different from the plots in the question after "The second image uses Epanechikov kernel and has artifacts where density drops to zero unexpectedly, I suspect I'm not selecting the bandwidth properly".

Comment: I'm afraid I'll not have a spare time to think about your first problem.  Sorry and regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand your non-comment code. Here is a partial answer to your question:`TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, SmoothKernelDistribution[svals,  Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 2}, "Epanechnikov"}]]` instead of your  `SmoothKernelDistribution[svals,  Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Epanechnikov"}]` helps with your second problem, outputting [image]

[image]

and so on. If I have a spare time, I'll think about your first problem.

Comment: The non-comment code is just there to generate sample data. Do you know what {0,2} means in the context of Epanechikov kernel? The kernel just has one parameter, not 2. For bounded data there's this [recipe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288065/visualizing-empirical-pdf-from-monotonically-decreasing-density/288174#288174) which occasionally works, but also fails in cases as its not adaptive

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: You asked " Do you know what {0,2} means in the context of Epanechikov kernel?". Yes, I know it: see "Compare smooth kernel distributions with a bounded Epanechnikov kernel:" in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html?q=SmoothKernelDistribution), namely, in the "Estimation in Fixed Domain" section. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.